# Как эффективно разделить задачу нахождения минимума и максимума между несколькими потоками. OpenMP

Tags: c++, многопоточность, оптимизация, распараллеливание, openmp

Попробовал осуществить попытку, но уже понял, что данная реализация только увеличивает время работы т.к. при каждом обращении к переменной min или max все потоки приостанавливают свое выполнение. Время выполнения, при 1000000 элементов, без распараллеливания 0.04с, с распараллеливанием 0.24с. Подскажите, как увеличить скорость работы при распараллеливание программы в данном случае?

```
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(t)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        #pragma omp critical(First)
        if (max < a[i]) max = a[i];

        #pragma omp critical(Second)
        if (min > a[i]) min = a[i];
    }
```

Comment: Уточните, что у вас за задача?

Comment: Попробуйте убрать напрочь секции `omp critical` и использовать `pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)`

Comment: для каждого потока заведите свою переменную max/min. потом слейте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этих целей есть специальное ограничение — *редукция* (*reduction*):

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(t) reduction(min:min_a) reduction(max:max_a)
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (max_a < a[i]) { max_a = a[i]; }
    if (min_a > a[i]) { min_a = a[i]; }
}
```

Смысл данного ограничения в том, что каждый поток будет работать со своей копией переменной, а потом объединит результаты работы всех потоков по заданному алгоритму.

Окромя `min`/`max` также допустимы следующие операторы: `+`, `-` , `*`, `&`, `^`, `|`, `&&`, `||`.